# How do I retrieve the notification object for PayPalTransactionDidSucceedNotification

Tags: paypal

The documentation says "The notification's object is the completed PayPalPayment, same as the delegate method."

But I still don't get it.  This is how I add the notification:
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(payPalCompletionHandler:)
       name:PayPalTransactionDidSucceedNotification
       object:nil];

```
-(void)payPalCompletionHandler:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // How do I get (PayPalPayment *)completedPayment?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, duh.

use this to get the notifications object.
    NSDictionary *myObject = [notification object];